# applying "this" jQuery, to delete an echoed row in php from sql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, row

This is my current plan:

Clicking on a row selects or gets the id of the row, then this id is passed to a delete script most likely via AJAX or an HTTP request. The problem I have is how to identify the row from the click using "this" this as in show below:

```
 $( this ) {
// get id and send to delete script
}
```

I have echoed out the rows so that I have the id row

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'dbconnect.php');

$link = new mysqli("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entries";

if ($result = $link->query($query)) {


    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        if($row[0]==0){
        echo "There are no entries.";
        }else {
        $query2 = "SELECT id,saying,date,thumbs_up,comments FROM entries ORDER by ID ASC ";

if (($result = $link->query($query2))) {
    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {

       echo 
       '<div class="container" align="center"">'.
       '<div class="entry-container" align="left">'.
       $row[1]." ".
       '</div>'.
       '<div class="x" align="center">'.
       '<button class="red" name="remove" onclick="remove_entry();">remove entry'.
       '&nbsp;'.
       $row[0].
       '</button>'.
       '</div>'.
       '</div>'.
       '<br>'
       ;

    }
    }
        }
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();

}

?>
```

`remove_entry();` doesn't do anything yet, presumably it will send the id to the delete script which then removes the row using the DELETE command

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function remove_entry() {
var answer = confirm("Delete this entry?")
if (answer){
       //some code
}
else{
        //some code
}
}
</script>
```

What is the most direct and effective / efficient way to do this?

I would even prefer not to show id, just use a simple x for the delete button, I echoed the id so that I had it to use to identify the row to be deleted.

Comment: you need an identifier like id to send to server to be able to perform db delete

Comment: Yeah I know, I mentioned that, hence I echoed the id via $row[0], I'm asking how does the click register the id selected which I have displayed. I mean I am aware that you can find elements with $(this) but how does this select the id and return it?

Comment: $(this).find('option:selected').text();

Comment: seems like you have to use tr / td's eg. old html that can't be right?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery can do :

HTML

```
<div class="entry-container" align="left" id="'.$row[0].'">
```

JS

```
$(function(){

    $('button.red').click(function(){
         var $row = $(this).closest('.entry-container'),
              rowId = $row.attr('id');

         $.post('/path/to/server', {id: rowId}, function(resp){
              if(resp =='ok'){
                  $row.slideUp(function(){ $row.remove() });
               }
         });
    });
});
```

Then remove your inline `onclick`

In PHP receive the id with `$_POST['id']` and validate it before passing to db query

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try and implement it. I have this ego thing I'm experiencing like "I should have figured this out myself." My approach was to use something I have used before where a "p" element is found and the value which I echoed the id by $row[0] would be used.... but I guess just get the job done right? Anyway, thank you.

Comment: well trying to parse text the way you have it embedded is far more complex than parsing attributes. If the id only filled one element would be simple, but you have it as a standalone text node in a container with other elements

Answer (score 1):

For starters, don't use 2 SQL queries. Just do the one you use to get data and, if it has no rows, give a different output.

Use semantic markup like so:

```
'<button type="button" class="remover" id="entry-' . $row[0] . '">remove this entry</button>'
```

Then in your jQuery, use something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.entries').on('click', '.remover', function() {
        var eId = this.id.replace(/^\D+/, '');//since IDs should not start with a number
        $.post(
            '/your/delete/endpoint/',
            {
                id: eId
            },
            function(data) {
                if (data.ok) {//sending JSON responses are easier to debug and you can add to them later without breaking things
                    //remove row
                }
                else {
                    //display error message
                }
            }
        );
    });
});
```

The second parameter to `on()` makes it a delegated event, which means you can add new items to an existing set, with the same remover markup, and the new remove buttons will also work.

Comment: curious about the first line $('.entries').on... why use that? I mean, the button is separate from the $row[1] or content being displayed, where did entries come from?

Comment: also what is this about id's not starting with a number? Does that lead to an error? I was trying to get the id by using $(.myClass).attr('id'); and if id can't be number then maybe it wasn't working because my id's were numbers?

Comment: `entries` was just an example class for the containing element of your list. The html spec says `id` shouldn't start with numbers. It makes code more readable to have the id actually reflect what the element represents. `$(.myClass).attr('id')` will always get the id from the first matched element in the set, so clicking any remove button would always delete the first in the list. You don't need to wrap native elements in a jQuery object just to read their properties, hence the `this.id`